# Where is the documentation on how to deploy .Net Core apps to Azure Webapps thru VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

There is documentation on creating and deploying 'Hello World' in Node.Js and deploying it in an Azure Webapp. 
https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/create-app

But there isn't documentation on doing the same with .Net Core. I have the 'Hello World' console app as per this.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet

I also have the 'Azure App Service' extension installed. How do I deploy the 'Hello World' to Azure Webapp.

I tried Github also. But they closed issue without action.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/10044

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I deploy the 'Hello World' to Azure Webapp.

We need to deploy the **Web Application** to Azure not **console** Application. I do a demo to deploy .net core webapp to Azure through VS code.

The following is detail steps.

1.Create a MVC web application with dotnet command.

```
dotnet new mvc
```

2.Publish the project to the local path.

```
dotnet publish webprojectName.csproj --output localpath
```

[image]

3.If Azure WebApp extension is installed, login with Azure account then you could create azure webapp and deploy the project to your Azure web

[image]

4.Select the created/existed Webapp and select the directory(published output local path) to deploy.

[image]

5.Check the output from VS code and browser the WebApp.

[image]